# Center-frequency parameter for gnuradio noise generator flowgraph

Tags: gnuradio

Can I add a center-frequency parameter for my noise generator flowgraph, is there a different noise source that has this parameter other than the generic noise source block?

[image]

Comment: the Noise source doesn't have something like a center frequency. And your Audio Sink can't support 2.2 MS/s. We address sampling rates in the [Official Guided Tutorials](https://tutorials.gnuradio.org).

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noise from that block doesn't have a center frequency because it's "white" — it has an equal power at *any* frequency (up to the half the sample rate, anyway, and you can extend that as far as you need). You can *give* it a shape by filtering it. Whatever the shape of the filter is, will be the shape of the resulting noise power. If you run it through a bandpass filter with a given center frequency, then the noise will have that center frequency.

Comment: Outstanding. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does the same thing apply when using Low Pass Filter?

Comment: @Hadad a lowpass doesn't have a center, it has a cutoff.

Comment: Where is the center frequency in the bandpass filter, is it the average of the low and high cutoff frequencies?

Comment: @hobbsKC2G, can I shape the noise  with the center frequency of the USRP device?

Comment: @Hadad you're asking multiple questions that really just indicate you don't understand digital signals and digital systems such as filters. Please read an introduction to Digital Signal Processing. [Maybe this](https://greatscottgadgets.com/sdr/). The way you're doing this right now honestly won't get you off the ground; get some basics.